# AngularJS "Verify" Directive Won't Compile Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

I am attempting to write a directive that, when added to a wrapper div around a button element, will add a verification step to invoking a given action. If a user clicks on a "dangerous" button, that button will disappear and be replaced by a red button with a check mark inside. When they click on the check mark, the action is invoked and the button returns to its normal state.

Currently I am experiencing the following problems with my directive:

- Clicking on the original button does not display the "verify" button **even though** `scope.verify` **changes**
- After setting `scope.verify` to true by default for testing purposes, clicking on the "verify" button does not invoke the expected action

**HTML**

```
<div verify>
  <label class="btn btn-default" data-click="resetFilters()">Clear Filters</label>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
angular.module("App").directive "verify", ["$compile",
  ($compile) ->

    directive = {}

    # This directive should be an attribute
    directive.restrict = "A"

    # We do not want to replace any HTML
    directive.replace = false

    # Skip the compilation of other directives
    directive.terminal = true

    # Compile this directive first
    directive.priority = 1001

    directive.link = (scope, element, attrs) ->

      # Remove verify attribute to prevent infinite compile loop
      element.removeAttr "verify"
      element.removeAttr "data-verify"

      # Select the element under the "verify" div, store the "click"
      # function and remove it from the element
      first = angular.element(element.children()[0])
      clickAction = first.attr "click" || first.attr "data-click"
      first.removeAttr "click"
      first.removeAttr "data-click"

      # Create a new element from the first one. This will become the
      # verify button
      second = first.clone()

      # Add the new element to the DOM
      element.append second

      # Add some custom ngShow / ngHide animation classes
      first.addClass "fader-down"
      second.addClass "fader-up"

      # Specify when each element should show / hide
      first.attr "ng-hide", "verify"
      second.attr "ng-show", "verify"

      # Design the verify button
      second.html "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"</span>"
      second.addClass "btn-danger"

      # Initially, only the original button should be visible
      scope.verify = false

      # When the user clicks on the original button, hide it and show
      # the verify button
      first.bind "click", ->
        scope.verify = true

      # When the user clicks on the second element, the "verify"
      # button, evaluate the specified "click" action. Hide the verify
      # button and show the original button
      second.bind "click", ->
        scope.$eval clickAction
        scope.verify = false

      # Compile the element
      $compile(element)(scope)
      # $compile(element.contents())(scope) # This doesn't work either

    return directive

]
```

Comment: can you put a plnker with this code? It will be easier to run and see what you are doing and what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind()` is a jqLite method (or a jQuery method if you are loading jQuery before Angular) and does not trigger the digest cycle for you. You will have to trigger it manually by wrapping it in a call to `scope.$apply()`:

```
first.bind('click', function () {
  scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.verify = true;
  });
});
```

And:

```
second.bind('click', function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.$eval(clickAction);
    scope.verify = false;
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/57X7IBcxafkN2U6W5IhE?p=preview